# How to compute the fixed field of an automorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Let $\sigma$ be the automophism of $\mathbb{Q}(\omega_5)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ that sends $\omega_5$ to $\omega_5^4$. I want to find the fixed field $(\mathbb{Q}(\omega_5))^\sigma$

Since $\sigma^2$ is the identity isomorfism we know that $(\{Id,\sigma\},\circ)$ is a subgroup of Gal$(\mathbb{Q}(\omega_5)/\mathbb{Q})$. The Galoisgroup has 4 elements, so the subgroup is normal. A normal subgroup corresponds to a Galois extension, so I know that the fixed field is a field extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ of index 2.

So if i could find a single element $u$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\omega_5)\setminus \mathbb{Q}$ such that $\sigma(u) = u$ I would be finished.

How does one (in this case or in general) find the fixed field?

Comment: I don't think that $\sigma$ is of order two.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I meant to write "$\sigma$ sends $\omega_5$ to $\omega_5^4$"

Comment: I see, thanks a lot!

Comment: $\sigma$ is the complex conjugation, since it just sends $\omega$ to $\overline \omega$. So all real numbers are fixed, hence the real part of $\omega$ (which is $\omega + \omega^4$ up to a factor $2$) is a good shot for the generator of the fixed field :)

Comment: In that case, let me give you a general strategy: when you have a subgroup, you should always try the trace and the norm of your generating element. Norm is no good here, but you'll see that $\omega+\omega^{-1}$ does the trick for you.